# Check if a item in created list appear on dataset['text'] column

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I created a list of bad words and a list of good words. 
I want to check if the words in the list appear in a specific dataset column

I use this code that apparently works but takes forever to execute. there is any other code that takes shorter time?

List:

```
restaurant_cleaned_reviews.text = restaurant_cleaned_reviews.text.str.lower()

good_words = ['great','amazing','love','best','awesome','excellent','good',
                                                    'favorite','loved','perfect','gem','perfectly','wonderful',
                                                    'happy','enjoyed','nice','well','super','like','better','decent','fine',
                                                    'pretty','enough','excited','impressed','ready','fantastic','glad','right',
                                                    'fabulous']
bad_words = ['bad','disappointed','unfortunately','disappointing','horrible',
                                                     'lacking','terrible','sorry', 'disappoint']
```

```
for word in restaurant_cleaned_reviews['text']:
    for good in good_words:
        if good in restaurant_cleaned_reviews['text']:
            restaurant_cleaned_reviews['Review'] = 'P'
    for bad in bad_words:
        if bad in restaurant_cleaned_reviews['text']:
            restaurant_cleaned_reviews = 'N'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create two specific functions:

```
def check_good_words(row):
    text_split = row['text'].split()
    for word in text_split:
        if word in good_words:
            return 1
    return 0

def check_bad_words(row):
    text_split = row['text'].split()
    for word in text_split:
        if word in bad_words:
            return 1
    return 0
```

Then:

```
restaurant_cleaned_reviews['contains_good_words'] = restaurant_cleaned_reviews.apply(check_good_words, axis=1)
restaurant_cleaned_reviews['contains_bad_words'] = restaurant_cleaned_reviews.apply(check_bad_words, axis=1)
```

I don't know if this is faster but most of the time it is :)

Answer (score 0):

```
good_words = ['good',awesome']
good_pattern = '|'.join(good_words)

bad_words = ['bad','awful','very bad']
bad_pattern = '|'.join(bad_words)

if restaurant_cleaned_reviews['text'].str.contains(good_pattern).any():
    restaurant_cleaned_reviews['Review']='P'
if restaurant_cleaned_reviews['text'].str.contains(bad_pattern).any():
    restaurant_cleaned_reviews['Review']='N'
```

This should work.

Comment: It gives me All Ns

Answer (score 0):

There are unnecessary for loops in your code. The first loop is O(n), where `n = len(restaurant_cleaned_reviews['text'])`. The inner for loop for `good_words` is another O(m), and [the `in` keyword is another O(n)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) . It is total O(n^2*m). It could be simplify:

```
# Remove first for loop (reduce by factor of n). O(mn)    
for good in good_words:
    if good in restaurant_cleaned_reviews['text']:
        restaurant_cleaned_reviews['Review'] = 'P'
```

But it could be improve further if you change the list to a set. Consider changing good_words to set using `good_words = set(good_words)`. Now searching using `in good_words` is log(m), much faster

```
# Change good_words to set
good_words = set(good_words)
for word in restaurant_cleaned_reviews['text']:
    if word in good_words:
        restaurant_cleaned_reviews['Review'] = 'P'
```